# A integral involving hyperbolic and trigonometric functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

So I have been pondering this question for a while, and nothing is coming through. I have tried multiple $u$-substitutions, and been attempting many other tricks I have learned, but it simply didn't come out. Also, Wolfram Alpha can't find a solution. This is the problem:
$$\int_0^1 \tanh(\cos(x)) dx$$

I understand there may be no closed form solution, but at least it is not an *indefinite* integral. At the least, a series representation would be okay.

Comment: [This](integral-calculator.com) website says the answer is $0.6795494048313782$ by numerical integration.

Comment: yes, but i already plugged it in to was, but I wanted a closed form or at the least a series representation, as stated in my question.

Comment: Another infinite series: $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{2 \ln \left(\frac{\sqrt{4+(1-2 k)^2 \pi ^2}+2 \sin (1)}{\sqrt{4+(1-2 k)^2 \pi ^2}-2 \sin (1)}\right)}{\sqrt{4+(1-2 k)^2 \pi ^2}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the faster would be to use the series expansion of $\tanh(t)$ which gives
$$ \tanh(\cos(x))=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^n \left(4^n-1\right) B_{2 n} }{(2 n)!}\cos ^{2 n-1}(x)$$ which leads to
$$I=\int_0^1\tanh(\cos(x))\,dx=$$ $$I=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \left(4^n-1\right) B_{2 n} \left(\frac{\pi }{n \Gamma
   \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}-\frac{4^n B_{\cos
   ^2(1)}\left(n,\frac{1}{2}\right)}{(2n)!}\right)$$

Computing the partial sums from $n=1$ to $n=p$, some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & \text{result} \\
 1 & 0.841471 \\
 2 & 0.627183 \\
 3 & 0.697668 \\
 4 & 0.673052 \\
 5 & 0.681934 \\
 6 & 0.678660 \\
 7 & 0.679885 \\
 8 & 0.679422 \\
 9 & 0.679598 \\
 10 & 0.679531 \\
 11 & 0.679557 \\
 12 & 0.679547 \\
 13 & 0.679551 \\
 14 & 0.679549 \\
 15 & 0.679550 \\
 16 & 0.679549
\end{array}
\right)$$

Composing the Taylor series in terms of $x$ would be a pure nightmare.

However, for a quick and dirty *approximation*, we could use the $[2n,2]$Padé approximant of the integrand. For example
$$\tanh(\cos(x))\sim \frac {t+a x^2+b x^4}{1+c x^2}$$ with
$$a=\frac{15 t^2-61 t+15}{30 (6 t-1)} \qquad b=\frac{21 \left(t^2-1\right)}{40 (6 t-1)}\qquad c=\frac{-90 t^2+30 t+29}{30 (6 t-1)}$$ and $t=\tanh(1)$. This would give as a result
$$I \sim  \frac {a+b}c-\frac{b}{c^2}+\frac{ c (c t-a)+b}{c^{5/2}}\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{c}\right)\sim 0.679076$$